# Nightwatch: Separate xpath into another files

Tags: testing, nightwatch.js

How to separate xpath into separate file and use it in nightwatch automation testing?

EDIT:
I running a page object pattern example and found some errors. 
Errors: TypeError: browser.page.url is not a function

Please help on this.

```
module.exports = {
 url: 'http://localhost:63916/Login/Login', 
 elements: {
 username: { 
 selector: '//*[@id="inputName"]', 
 locateStrategy: 'xpath' 
 }
 }
};

module.exports = (function(settings) {
    settings.test_workers = false;

    return settings;

})(require('./nightwatch.json'));

//const data = require('./data.js')


module.exports = {

    'Login' : function (browser) {
        var page = browser.page.url();

        page.navigate()
            .setValue('@username', 'peter')

        browser.end()

    }


};
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you want to accomplish. Your question does not make it clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please add the file names that you have used for these? And I hope you configured the `page_objects_path` also in your config? Please post the config you have used as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming the page object is defined in `pages` directory. You need to change your `nightwatch.conf.js` like below

**nightwatch.conf.js**

```
module.exports = (function(settings) {
    settings.test_workers = false;
    settings.page_objects_path = "./pages";
    return settings;
})(require('./nightwatch.json'));
```

Your `pages` has a file named `main.js`

**pages/main.js**

```
module.exports = {
    url: 'https://gmail.com',
    elements: {
        username: {
            selector: '//*[@id="identifierId"]',
            locateStrategy: 'xpath'
        },
        next: {
            selector: '#identifierNext span',
            locateStrategy: 'css'
        }
    }
};
```

And then you test is like below

**tests/test.main.js**

```
module.exports = {

    'Login' : function (browser) {
        var page = browser.page.main();

        page.navigate()
            .setValue('@username', 'peterlalwani')
            .click('@next')
            .waitForElementNotPresent("@username", 10000);

        browser.saveScreenshot("./so.png")
        browser.end()

    }

};
```

Now when you run it, it creates a `so.png`

[image: Test output]

I created a sample repo for you to clone and see the above

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/nightwatch-page-object-so.git

PS: It is important to note that `var page = browser.page.main();` means it would load `main.js` from the `pages` folder here.